# AWS Cognito with ASP.NET Core REST API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm attempting to do the following:

Take a token that has been successfully generated using AWS Cognito and allow that token to be used to hit a specific controller in a ASP.NET simple REST API setup.

I already successfully have Cognito setup, and issuing tokens based on a SAML link to ADFS.  I can get a token via Postman from Cognito and when I use this token with API gateway behind a mock method linked to that Cognito configuration, it successfully works so I know the token being generated and using that to auth against API Gateway works.

So following this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/now-generally-available-the-asp-net-core-identity-provider-for-amazon-cognito -- it should be pretty simple.

I have in my appsettings.json

```
"AWS": {
    "Region": "us-east-2",
    "UserPoolClientId": "xxx",
    "UserPoolClientSecret": "xxx",
    "UserPoolId": "us-east-2_xxxxxx"
  },
```

In `Startup.cs`, as the guide outlines, under `ConfigureServices`, among a few other settings, I have `services.AddCognitoIdentity();` and lastly I have `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure`.

In my API controller, I simply have `[Authorize(Roles = "readonly")]` which is the name of the group in the Cognito userpool the user who successfully authenticated against Cognito is in.

When I use that same token hitting the .NET Core API directly using the setup above, it fails without really any messages of value and then tries to forward the API call to https://localhost:8080/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/api/test which returns (in this case Postman) a 404.

```
2020-04-13 20:28:38.495 -05:00 [Information] Service=Services Env=VM Context=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService Authorization failed.
2020-04-13 20:28:38.499 -05:00 [Information] Service=Services Env=VM Context=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
2020-04-13 20:28:38.508 -05:00 [Information] Service=Services Env=VM Context=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]).
2020-04-13 20:28:38.537 -05:00 [Information] Service=Services Env=VM Context=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
```

I've tried both on .NET Core 2.2 and 3.1 with no success.

Ultimately I'm trying to maintain multiple user groups in a Cognito pool, and based on that group, authorize (or not) someone the ability to use a specific API in a controller.  It looks simple on the guide above, hopefully I'm just missing something silly.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?